# Use variable as WHERE filter for multiple strings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a field containing event codes, sometimes two, sometimes 3.

Column looks like this:

```
'3011, 6009'      
'3011, 3054'      
'3011, 3013'      
'6009, 9524'      
'3011, 9524'      
'3011, 6009, 3054'
'3011, 6009, 9524'
'3011, 9950'      
'6009, 9950'
```

The combinations define a certain group.

I want to use a variable @x and set the values. So far, so good.

But I am not sure how to use the variable in my SELECT statement:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM TableA
WHERE EventCodes IN (@x)
```

Can anyone point out where the quotes go in this, I can't find it.

Comment: what will be the values in the variable @x? is it going to be a single number or multiple commas separated values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IN` clause wants a set of elements. A variable, as your, is one string with concatenation of your elements, so are very different.

You can create a temp table as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE #app
(id varchar(10))
```

INSERT INTO #app VALUES ('3011, 6009'), and so on

Then, you can re-write your query as follow:

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM TableA
WHERE EventCodes IN (SELECT id FROM #app)
```

or

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM TableA
JOIN #app
    ON TableA.EventCode = #app.id
```

Comment: Not exactly what I needed, but you lead me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on 2016, you can use the new [STRING_SPLIT](http://www.itprotoday.com/microsoft-sql-server/parsing-denormalized-strings-stringsplit-function-sql-server-2016) function. It'll take your comma-delimited string and return a table, which you can use in an `IN` clause.  For example,

```
SELECT A, B, C
FROM   TableA
WHERE  EventCodes IN STRING_SPLIT(@X, ',')
```

It'd be better if you could normalize your tables though.

Comment: We're on 2008, but thanks. As for normalization, with you there, but in this case not in my hands.